# How to use both BallonItemizedOverlay along with Double taps and long clicks on maps in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone please let me know how to implement both BallonItemizedOverlay and double taps and long press on maps in android? I have implemented the Ballon Itemized Overlay but I don't know how to achieve the both double clicks and long press along with the BallonItemized Overlay in android?